Is it possible to convert a single row of data to multiple rows and columns?
Is it possible to convert a single row of data to multiple rows and columns?
Example:
SELECT 
    1 AS A1,
    2 AS A2,
    3 AS B1,
    4 AS B2
FROM dual;

 A1 | A2 | B1 | B2
__________________
 1  | 2  | 3  | 4

Desired output:
 A  | B
_________
 1  | 3
_________
 2  | 4


Is this a real problem? If not, then better move it to https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Yes, I had this problem at work but couldn't find a solution on Stack Overflow. I found a solution and wanted to share it as a general problem/answer.

The most simple way would be to use Union All since there are just sample data and expected result.
WITH    -- S a m p l e   D a t a :
    one_row_tbl AS
        ( Select 1 "A1", 2 "A2", 3 "B1", 4 "B2"
          From   Dual
        )

--    S Q L :
Select  A1 "A", B1 "B" From one_row_tbl Union All 
Select  A2 "A", B2 "B" From one_row_tbl

/*  R e s u l t :
         A          B
---------- ----------
         1          3
         2          4  */

There is no explanation of the logic to be applyed. Is it, realy, the first letter of a column name as it looks like. It could be that the names of columns were X1, X2, X3, X4 and you want to group them to get the same result then you should provide some logic explained.
Let's say that sample data is like this:
WITH
    one_row_tbl AS
        ( Select 10 "X1", 30 "X2", 40 "X3", 20 "X4"
          From   Dual
        ), 

... and you want values that are less or equal to average in column A and those greater than average in column B. That could be just one possible logic. In this case, to transpond the one row of data into two columns and two rows, the code (one option) could be ...
-- cte to unpivot and prepare the data
    avg_grouped AS
        ( Select COL_VALUE, AB, Row_Number() Over(Partition By AB Order By COL_VALUE) "RN"
          From   ( Select COL_VALUE,
                           Case When COL_VALUE <= Avg(col_value) Over() Then 'A' Else 'B' End "AB"
                    From   one_row_tbl
                      UNPIVOT ( col_value FOR col_name IN (X1, X2, X3, X4) )
                 )
        )

--    M a i n    S Q L :
Select  A, B
From    avg_grouped
PIVOT ( Max(COL_VALUE) FOR AB IN('A' as A, 'B' as B) )

/*    R e s u l t :
         A          B
---------- ----------
        10         30
        20         40  */


This is the solution I was looking for. I'm very new to SQL and thought it had to be simpler than the solution I found in my answer.

Here’s how you can transform a single row into multiple rows and columns:

Use the UNPIVOT operation to convert columns into rows.
Use a row numbering mechanism to create a unique identifier for each new row.
Use the PIVOT operation to convert the rows back into the desired format.

Here's how to achieve this with the example:
WITH data AS (
    SELECT 
        1 AS A1,
        2 AS A2,
        3 AS B1,
        4 AS B2
    FROM dual
),
unpivoted AS (
    SELECT 
        col_group,
        col_type,
        col_value,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col_group ORDER BY col_type) AS rn
    FROM data
    UNPIVOT (
        col_value FOR col_name IN (A1, A2, B1, B2)
    )
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT 
            SUBSTR(col_name, 1, 1) AS col_group, 
            SUBSTR(col_name, 2) AS col_type 
        FROM dual
    )
)
SELECT
    --col_type AS A, -- Uncomment to see col_type (1, 2)
    MAX(CASE WHEN col_group = 'A' THEN col_value END) AS A,
    MAX(CASE WHEN col_group = 'B' THEN col_value END) AS B
FROM unpivoted
GROUP BY rn--, col_type -- Uncomment to see col_type (1, 2)
ORDER BY rn;

Explanation:

CTE data:
WITH data AS (
    SELECT 
        1 AS A1,
        2 AS A2,
        3 AS B1,
        4 AS B2
    FROM dual
),

This Common Table Expression (CTE) defines the initial row with columns A1, A2, B1, and B2.

CTE unpivoted:
unpivoted AS (
    SELECT 
        col_group,
        col_type,
        col_value,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col_group ORDER BY col_type) AS rn
    FROM data
    UNPIVOT (
        col_value FOR col_name IN (A1, A2, B1, B2)
    )
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT 
            SUBSTR(col_name, 1, 1) AS col_group, 
            SUBSTR(col_name, 2) AS col_type 
        FROM dual
    )
)

This CTE performs the UNPIVOT operation, transforming columns into rows. The CROSS APPLY statement is used to extract the col_group (A or B) and col_type (1 or 2). The ROW_NUMBER function assigns a unique row number for each group.

Final SELECT:
SELECT
    col_type AS A, -- Uncomment to see col_type (1, 2)
    MAX(CASE WHEN col_group = 'A' THEN col_value END) AS A_value,
    MAX(CASE WHEN col_group = 'B' THEN col_value END) AS B_value
FROM unpivoted
GROUP BY rn --, col_type --Uncomment to see col_type (1, 2)
ORDER BY rn;

In the final SELECT statement, the MAX function with CASE is used to pivot the data back into the desired format. The GROUP BY clause groups by the row number and column type to get the correct structure. I left col_type commented, because it wasn't in the given example desired output, but it may be useful in production.



KISS:
select a1 AS a, b1 AS b from data
union all
select a2, b2 from data
;


The @p3consulting KISS solution has been posted already...

... page was not refreshed when I posted...

Not a problem at all @p3consulting. Loved to see KISS here. Personaly, I use it a lot.

But since this question looks a lot like a XY-one... if the problematic is more general and requires moving N tuples of columns to rows, then you should better use MODEL to avoid multiple scans of the table:
(of course for the strict scope of the question this solution would be seen as a MICS one...)
example moving 3 pairs of columns to rows:
WITH data(a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3) AS (
    SELECT 
        1 AS A1,
        2 AS A2,
        5 AS A3,
        3 AS B1,
        4 AS B2,
        6 AS B3
    FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        5 AS A1,
        6 AS A2,
        9 AS A3,
        7 AS B1,
        8 AS B2,
        10 AS B3
    FROM DUAL
), 
rdata(id, a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3) AS (
    SELECT rownum,a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3
    FROM data
)
SELECT id, a,b from rdata
-- 3 is the number of tuples of columns, here 3 pairs
CROSS APPLY(SELECT LEVEL AS k FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3)
MODEL
    DIMENSION BY ( id, k )
    MEASURES( 0 as a, 0 as b, a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3)
    RULES (
        a[any,1] = a1[cv(),cv()],
        b[any,1] = b1[cv(),cv()],
        a[any,2] = a2[cv(),cv()],
        b[any,2] = b2[cv(),cv()],
        a[any,3] = a3[cv(),cv()],
        b[any,3] = b3[cv(),cv()]
    )
ORDER BY id
;

